# Facebook APP post the story once

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

I am using the $facebook->api to auto-post a story when user accepts my application and reads the story on my web-site. This all works fine but the problem is when he refreshes the page, or re-visits the page, the same story/link gets re-posted on his wall! 
How can I publish the story once for one user! 
I am doing this in wordpress!

```
include_once("fb_config.php");
        //Setup Facebook post url and login url
        $post_url = '/'.$fbuser.'/feed';
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
             'canvas' => 1,
             'fbconnect' => 0,
             'scope' => $fbPermissions,
             'redirect_uri'=>$homeurl
        ));
        //Setup the message to be posted on users wall
        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID, 'thumbnail') );
        $description = my_excerpt( $post->post_content, $post->post_excerpt );
        $description = strip_tags($description);
        $description = str_replace("\"", "'", $description);
        $p_title = html_entity_decode(get_the_title(), ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $news = array(
            'message'       => '',
            'name'          => htmlspecialchars_decode($p_title),
            'link'          => get_permalink($post->ID),
            'caption'       => get_bloginfo ( 'description' ),
            'description'   => $description,
            'picture'       => $thumbnail
        );

    if ($fbuser) {
      try {
            $postResult = $facebook->api($post_url, 'post', $news );
        } 
        catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo '<script>top.location.href = "'.$loginUrl.'"</script>';
      }
    }else{
        echo '<script>top.location.href = "'.$loginUrl.'"</script>';
    }
```

Comment: Can you post some code here, the auto-posting part in particular ?

Comment: e dited the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

Create a db table like:

```
[user_article_posted]
user_article_posted_id
user_id
article_id
```

Every time a user reads(loads) an article and **if is logged in via facebook**, check if there s a combination of user_id/article_id record.

1. If there is: do not post to facebook
2. If not: insert new row to that table(user/article) and post story to facebook

The user_id could also be fbuser depending on your structure.

Comment: This is a great idea, thnx mallix i tried with coockies and sessions but that didn't work well!

Comment: Yeah no need to use sessions here. Just check if the user posted the article in the past (using that table to track records) and you are good to go.

Comment: Malix I got it to work and accepted your answer. I found out that if users delete the story from their wall I will not be able to repost again because my story exists on my db! :S Maybe there is a way with fb-api to check weather the link exists on users wall

Comment: This of course is full optimization for your feature. So when you post something to a user s wall, you get back a bigint value. Add another column to the table, for example "post_id" and store that value ($postResult) to the same table. So except checking the database for user/article combination, check also if the object with the post_id still exists as a post on user s facebook. I think that you need the read_stream permission also to accomplish this.

Comment: That sounds great, i currently use only publish_actions. I will look into the facebook api how that works.